Is present perfect necessary here
"He has won the lottery today. He is rich now."
"He  won the lottery today. He is rich now"
I think both are possible
The first sentence connects "the winning" to "impending wealth" and insists on the connection between both events and the direct impact on  the present state and the second one states facts without a stronger connection than the first .
My question: it is obvious in both sentences that the fact of being rich comes from playing the lottery so do we need really present perfect here ?

No, it's not necessary, though many (especially British) speakers would choose to use it.

I'd prefer the present perfect because while his lottery numbers came up he probably hasn't got the money yet and he's still the lottery winner, so it's something that continues from the past into the present. Unless it was a competition where they give you the money immediately. But the connection is obvious.

The first one is extremely unlikely. Haven't you learned by now to avoid unnecessary use of Perfect verb forms? It seems to me telling learners that is the primary purpose of ELL these days.

...also note that on the (relatively uncommon) occasions when a speaker would use Present Perfect for something done earlier today, we almost never use it for unusual / unlikely things. So whereas I've had three cups of coffee today is normal (especially if followed by something like ...so I'm a bit hyped up on caffeine). Whereas I've got married today is probably just weird - even if followed by ...so I'm looking forward to legitimate sex tonight. Imho, winning the pools is more like getting married than drinking coffee, in terms of "significant activity".

@FumbleFingers - But "I've just got married!" isn't 'weird' - not to me, at least. "I've won the lottery" seems to me a prime example of 'event in the past directly related to the present', as Grammarly puts it.

@KateBunting: I think we must agree to differ. Do you not even acknowledge my point about "significant" prior events / actions? Whatever, even if you as a native don't think the Perfect is "odd" in OP's context, surely you're not suggesting you think Simple Past is "unusual". I'm convinced far too many learners obsess about totally unnecessary use of Perfect forms. They should be encouraged to adopt the default Use Perfect only when necessary, rather than Use Perfect wherever possible (because your non-native Anglophone teachers want to see proof that you can do this).

@FumbleFingers - Note that I said in my original comment that the present perfect is not necessary (though I personally would find it more idiomatic). I must be a dinosaur, because I sometimes hear native speakers on TV use constructions which seem unidiomatic to me.

I did notice that. In normal circumstances I wouldn't want to sound critical of another native Anglophones preferred choice of phrasing - especially not yours, since if I recall you have a background in librarianship! Our "difference of opinion" isn't really about your preference - it's about the fact that when learners see what you write, they probably pay more attention to that than they do to my NGrams usage chart. Which shows a very strong preference for Simple Past in [have] won today, that's almost certainly even stronger in conversational (not "published") text.

...and that probably accords with what they get from their nns teachers, who are probably tempted to overplay Perfect forms because they can explain them in ways that seem to make sense.
